# Performance tuning for progress 4gl oracle data server

Tags: database, oracle, progress-4gl, openedge

I have read in perfomance tuning articles that if we skip-schema-check, it will improve data server perfomance, in turn will speed up query execution. I am using oracle databse for financial enterprise application and want to increase query performance. How much perfomance increase can be achieved using skip schema check ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are having a performance problem with your server. I would follow the performance tuning process on your Oracle, turning on oracle trace files, and running your application for a while, then then analyzing the results. Note that your system will probably run VERY slowly while the trace is on and could generate a lot of files.

Analyzing the trace files will show you which statements are using the most elapsed and system time, and that will show you which queries are causing the most delay, and if they are "application" queries, or Progress querying the schema.

Do you have the oracle SQL optimizer running? There is always a risk that the Progress Oracle Dataserver is generating queries that Oracle isn't optimizing well. When you've found the worst offending SQL queries in Oracle, it will also tell you how Oracle is approaching the query and whether it is using sensible indexes. The optimiser is very good most of the time, but just occasionally gets it very wrong, and requires a "hint" to set it right. If you are using the optimiser make sure that the statistics are being kept up-to-date as that can really throw the optimiser in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yes I have oracle optimier running. Now we have stopped hint from progress data server as we found out those index are taking much time than one which oracle can use without hint. But again there is problem of ordering records.

Comment: I suspect that is the reason progress uses the specific index hints, since it assumes records are always read according to the order of the index. It's a tricky one. You could specify the right indexes in the progress code if you have access to it.